# MSMQ : Cursor and Priority

Tags: msmq

Here is the code to enumerate the messages.

```
MessageQueue  queue = // ... some local private queue
Cursor cursor = queue.CreateCursor();

Message msg = queue.Peek(timeout, cursor, PeekAction.Current);
while( msg != null )
{
  // ... process
  msg = queue.Peek(timeout, cursor, PeekAction.Next);
}
```

Suppose I have 100 HIGH priority messages and 10000 LOW priority messages in the queue.

So it would peek the messages in following order.

`HIGH  #1
HIGH  #2
HIGH  #3
...
HIGH  #99
HIGH  #100
LOW   #101
LOW   #102
...
LOW   #10000`

Now suppose the code starts to run,  it first handled the 100 HIGH priority messages then starts to handles the low priority messages.

At some point it peeked up a LOW priority as below.

`LOW   #8243   <-- cursor is here now
LOW   #8244
...
LOW   #10000`

Now a new HIGH priority message arrived in the queue.

My question is:

**Will the HIGH priority message be peeked up immediately for the next call to `queue.Peek(timeout, cursor, PeekAction.Current)` ?**